# Code-First Migrations MissingManifestResourceException

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I am currently working on creating the InitialCreate migration for a new database.  I am new to this migration framework and do not know exactly what it generates, I have been running `update-database` to see the result, dropping the database then running `update-database` again after making some changes to see the results.

Twice now I have made some changes, went to run the update and gotten an error like this:

> Applying code-based migration: 201209121936571_InitialCreate.
>   System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "$assemblyName$.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "$assemblyName$" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
>      at [StackTrace]

Then it ends in red with

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "$assemblyName$.Migrations.InitialCreate.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "$assemblyName$" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

The first time I encountered this I dropped the migration folder, ran `enable-migrations` re-made my changes and was able to run the migration.

It has happened again and I am not wanting to have to recreate the files every time this happens.  Does anyone know how to correct this to make the migration work again?

Comment: Refer to this thread, it solved my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17484445/193634

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring this our in the course of pulling together all the information I wanted for asking the question.  Namely, trying to reproduce the issue.

It turns out that if you have a class other than the inheritor of DbMigration as the first class in the file, the Resource file takes the name of the other class and not the migration which breaks the migration.

I have filed a bug report [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/511).

Answer (score 14):

For me solution was to add folowing code in .csproj file of my projected, inside `<PropertyGroup>`

```
<EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>true</EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>
```

Afted that Update-Database command worked fine.

Comment: +1, we had this error after migrating the project with EF from .NET framework to .NET Standard 2.1. Here's the original issue on github https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/1258#issuecomment-531355034

Comment: @kurdemol94 Great idea to give credit to the author of that comment. Well done! - Sad, though, that 8 years later this fundamental problem has still not been properly addressed by the toolset.

Comment: We also had this problem in an SDK-style project targeting net471 with EF 6.4.0 (not EF Core). It appears as if it the target is not relevant. Instead it depends on the format of the project file.

Answer (score 1):

I have the problem with **Entity Migration, Entity 6.4 and with Microsoft.Net.SDK style project in Full .Net Framework**.

I resolved it by editing my Data project with :

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="**\*.resx">
      <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileName)')).cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```