# System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException when Updating database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I moved a web application I am working on from one machine to another. It is built using .Net MVC and Entity Framework but when I execute the `Update-Database` command so that the database is updated, I get this error:

```
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "NameofMigration.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "NameofProject" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code-First Migrations MissingManifestResourceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417737/code-first-migrations-missingmanifestresourceexception)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I had a similar issue when the resx part of the migration was not included in the project file when a fellow developer checked the project in (probably due to a merge issue).  You may find that the resx file is there but greyed out.  If it's there, try right clicking the "NameofMigration.resx" file and selecting "include in project".  If it's not there, you better go find it on the other machine and add it to the project :-)

Comment: Happened to me after conflict resolution in Git. Solution worked.

Comment: Remember to build project after including .resx file.

Answer (score 12):

I think the issue (one issue) is that the .resx file is added as "dependent upon" (nested under) the .cs file, and the way the build engine works, "dependent upon" changes the name that an embedded resource is saved with (something like, it changes from being based on the filename to being based on the type name; I've dealt with this in other scenarios but can't remember for sure).

This leads to problems when using SDK .csproj files, for some reason (I guess that by default SDK .csproj does *not* change the resource name in this situation, but the migrations system expects it to).

As someone else had posted, SDK .csproj can use the following tag to change the embedded resource naming scheme for "dependent upon" resources, which then allows the migrations system to find the embedded resource:

```
<EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>
  true
</EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>
```

This should go in a `<PropertyGroup>` of your SDK .csproj file.

Comment: Huge help! thanks. Solved my problem having update csproj to the sdk format

Comment: Had to have no newlines, then it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For VS 2017, the solution is as follows:

Go to the project file, and for all of the migrations, apply the following format:

```
 <Compile Include="Migrations\201804251606403_emailsWithEffort.cs" />
<Compile Include="Migrations\201804251606403_emailsWithEffort.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>201804251606403_emailsWithEffort.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>

    <EmbeddedResource Include="Migrations\201804251606403_emailsWithEffort.resx">
  <DependentUpon>201804251606403_emailsWithEffort.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

I guess that the problem is when changing version(s) of Visual Studio, old format of describing dependencies stays, and the Visual Studio 2017 can not interpret it correctly.

Hence, applying the format as described above (change your format to this), you can make the Visual Studio get the idea of where it's resources are.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different situation, where I created a new environment, and database, and received the above error message.

For my fix, I had to right-click on the migration files (initial and resx) and set property to embedded as resource. Update-database command ran fine afterward.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue (VS 2017) and none of the solutions provided here worked. I fixed the problem by cleaning the solution and manually deleting the bin folder and then building it again.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody wants to look into the source or compiler to know why this is happening; I don't feel like it right now.  After an hour of tinkering, my resolution is odd.

Granted, I shouldn't have done this in the first place, but for quick code I temporarily added classes into the same file as my generated `DbMigration` `201906212110305_initial.cs`.  The mere existence of those temporary classes in the same file caused this error.  As soon as I moved them to their own file (which I was going to do all along anyway) the runtime error vanished.

Comment: This worked for me. To fix I needed to move my added class to the bottom of the file. My guess is the class file was a "partial class" so the added class declaration at the top interupted half way through compiling the partial class.

Answer (score 0):

Unloading and then reloading migration file worked for me!